# Shell Script not running when I connect a USB

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to run a shell script when my iPhone connects to my Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian

Here's what I have so far:
at /etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="05ac", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1227", RUN+="/home/pi/testscript.sh"
```

How can I check that this script is actually running, because I don't think it is, and is this the correct syntax?

Comment: Why not have your script write to a log file whenever it runs?

Comment: @Jesse_b nothing is appearing in the log when I connect the device

Comment: Is `usbmuxd` installed on your system? If yes then there is probably another udev rule for iPhones on your system which might override your udev rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your script must be executable.

Do this step by step to find out your problem:

First create a simple script:

`sudo nano /bin/device_added.sh`

Add the following lines in the `device_added.sh` script

`#!/bin/bash
echo "USB device added at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log`

Open the second script.

`sudo nano /bin/device_removed.sh`

Then add the following lines to `device_removed.sh` script.

`#!/bin/bash
echo "USB device removed  at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log`

Save the files, close and make both scripts executable.

`$ sudo chmod +x /bin/device_added.sh
$ sudo chmod +x /bin/device_removed.sh`

Next, let’s create a rule to trigger execution of the above scripts, called `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-test.rules`

`nano /etc/udev/rules.d/80-test.rules`

Add these two following rules in it.

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",  RUN+="/bin/device_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/bin/device_removed.sh"`

Save the file and close it. Then as root, tell systemd-udevd to reload the rules files (this also reloads other databases such as the kernel module index), by running.

`sudo udevadm control --reload`

Now connect your iphone or any other usb drive into your machine and check if the `device_added.sh` script was executed. First of all the file `scripts.log` should be created under `/tmp`.

Then the file should have an entry such as “USB device removed at date_time”

If this steps worked correctly the you can replace the `/bin/device_added.sh` script with your script. and place your rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-test.rules`

[udev-for-device-detection-management-in-linux](https://www.tecmint.com/udev-for-device-detection-management-in-linux/)

Comment: You should not put stuff in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. `/usr/local/bin` is for that.

Comment: Can you explain why `/bin` is not good for such stuff? i can change my answer if you have reliable source for your comment.@ ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: The installer modifies `/bin` etc. So it is best to avoid it.`/usr/local/` is designed for you to put your own stuff in. Its layout mirrors the root fs.

Comment: And why do you think that `/home/pi` is not accessible?

Comment: Thanks @ctrl-alt-delor. because i think the answer must be useful to others too. `/home/pi` is on  Raspbian only but `/bin` is on all distros.

Answer (score 1):

Run `udevadm monitor` and plug the USB device. It will show you what exactly udev does.