# Detect USB FT232R UART and run script

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have ser2net working perfectly with a USB FT232R UART (Creality 3D printer) using setserial to work with the higher speed of 250000 baud. The problem is that when I turn off the printer and turn back on, I have to run again the setserial commands to make the port available for ser2net.
Is there a way to automate this upon connection?

The commands i need to run:

> setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0 spd_cust
>
> setserial -a /dev/ttyUSB0 divisor 96

Kind regards,
Eric

Comment: Most likely you will have to write a script to modify the loadable drivers. See "https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux-1.pdf". Also. plugin the printer - without running the setserial commands - and type "dmesg | grep FTDI" then post the output.

Comment: You need to write a `udev` rule, and a small `systemd` unit. This [existing question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544204/shell-script-not-running-when-i-connect-a-usb?rq=1) has pointers to commands you can use to advance in your quest.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that did the trick ;-)

Comment: I reverted the mast recent edit adding "SOLVED" to the title. If there exists a solution, then please add this as an answer. Accepting the answer then marks the question as resolved.